# Deserialization failed from session variable. crystalreportdocument in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, crystal-reports, serializable

Deserialization failed from session variable. crystalreportdocument in asp.net.

this code works fine inside aspx.cs file:

```
Session["Report"] = crReportDocument;

var zx=Session["Report"];
ReportDocument crDoc = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Report"] as ReportDocument;
```

But It doesn't work when inside a utility class in different project after  I changed:
From:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc".....
```

To:

```
<sessionState mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424"  
                  stateNetworkTimeout="60"/>
```

Class `ReportDocument` has the `Serializable` attribute.

Error shows:

> {"Deserialization failed.  You need to run
>   \"rassdk://D:\Development\Projects\Xweb\UI\Report_RPT\EOD\rptPort_Margin.rpt\"
>   on a Report Application Server."}